# Good way to relate filepath with object

Tags: c#, design-patterns

How should I store the relation of the filepath that the object was created or saved to?

Ex:

```
string path = @"C:\File.ext";
MyObject obj = new MyObject(path);
```

The app will store multiples MyObject, how would you store the relations (MyObject - path)? A Dictionary? A new class? One solution is adding a property Path to the MyObject class, but I think it is a bad idea. I mean, it is not the file job to "know" were it is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a `Dictionary<MyObject, string>` is good. You could do something like this:

```
string path = @"C:\File.ext";
MyObject obj = new MyObject(path);
_sharedDictionary.Add(obj, path);
```

and then later on:

```
string path;
var found = _sharedDictionary.TryGetValue(obj, out path);
```

Comment: Humm nice, I'll try it. I was just wondering how people use to do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a dictionary with path as a key and a list of MyObjects as a value

Comment: I think it is best to use the object as key, because it can have a null path, if it was created internally and never saved.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer solution with additional container class for storing your object and path to it.

Especially if you will need to store some additional info except path (like e.g. date) or you will try to search for objects via their properties.